# Django static files not loading, though the correct links show in view source

Tags: django, sass, static

Static files located at top level of project not loading correctly in Django 2.1.3.  When I do a view source of the page the path is correct and i can click on the link, showing me that, indeed, the content is there.  Inspecting the page, however, shows no stylesheets are loaded.  Its a standard dev setup.  Was working fine. The only factors that could be contributing are that i had to reinstall django and just straight replaced the basic new project folder with a copy of my project.  In the process, I also installed it in a new virtual env (same name). The admin page seems to work ok along with the rest of the code, so the entire world didnt break.  The only other change was installing SASS and trying to integrate Bootstrap 4 at a local level (not messing with the standard folder layout). Wont work with the compiled SASS css (Interestingly, when i viewed the link in the source the changes were present) or any other simple hand written css.  Static JS is also broken.  The links and code seem ok in source, just not loading.

SOLVED: Simple moron behind the wheel.  Used "type" instead of "rel" in my link... smh...

Comment: did you [hard refresh](https://packback.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360003031611-How-can-I-hard-refresh-my-browser-) your browser?

Comment: Yeah, even tried other browsers.  I did notice that the browsers cache static includes, but yes, tried.

Comment: Is it occurring only in production or everywhere(local & prod)?

Comment: What does the Network tab of the inspector say? Does it even attempt to load the resource? You might have a typo in your `<script>` or `<link>` tags.

Comment: I dont have it on a production server as of yet, just using XAMPP.  The network only shows my linked resources like Jquery, etc.  Editor: <link type="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">   Source: <link type="stylesheet" href="/static/css/main.css">.  (i even tried the "type='text/css'")..... holy $%!@....

Answer (score 0):

link type="...  instead of link rel="..., simple typo, yikes lol  Gotta pay more attention I guess.